# How to get values from multiple tables based on Id and create new based on ids

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need some help, I looked for a solution in other posts but I couldn't make those solutions work.

I have a table that contains a bunch of id's...

```
table1

customerId | adsId | campaignId |   contextId   |    Date    | amoutDue
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234341233 | 4r4w3 |  cp123sifs | cbgvss23r23dd | 03-09-2021 |    50
4556666666 | 35533 |  cp453f44f | cb2d3d23dd33d | 04-06-2021 |    25
3444468766 | 12345 |  cpef4f44r | ccascasca333s | 23-04-2021 |    13
6346522452 | qw324 |  cpfe4r333 | c23ddsasssd2f | 12-07-2021 |    71
3463466346 | 23423 |  cp1vt5rfr | kjhcbwiytcubp | 25-02-2021 |    41
4534634346 | 534f3 |  cp4343ff4 | apisuchha9shh | 14-05-2021 |    36
7743646346 | wer32 |  cp4ffwefe | cq98hd98ladse | 12-03-2021 |    53
2424233335 | r4w4r |  cpwerewff | q09jucidnionc | 05-06-2021 |    65
```

In another table I have the `adsId` and `adsName`:

```
table2(adsId/adsName)

  adsName  | adsId 
--------------------
ad-google1 | 4r4w3 
ad-fbtests | 35533
ad-bingpro | 12345 
ad-maillan | qw324 
ad-cp-e312 | 23423 
ad-gads2-4 | 534f3 
ad-adProsk | wer32 
ad-cpcB151 | r4w4r
```

On the 3rd table I have `campaingName` and `campaingId`:

```
table3(campaingId/campaignName)

campaignName | campaignId
------------------------
cp-adWords   | cp123sifs 
cp-looki12   | cp453f44f
cp-cvccp53   | cpef4f44r
cp-Pliiltr   | cpfe4r333
cp-Yellinf   | cp1vt5rfr
cp-Iuliucs   | cp4343ff4
cp-Ieventx   | cp4ffwefe
cp-Shoofab   | cpwerewff
```

Finally the 4th table I have `contextId` and `contextName`:

```
table4(contextId/contextName)

   contextId   | contextName 
-----------------------------
 cbgvss23r23dd | ctx-Okkels  
 cb2d3d23dd33d | ctx-Yumeis  
 ccascasca333s | ctx-Niehok   
 c23ddsasssd2f | ctx-Sluiru 
 kjhcbwiytcubp | ctx-Strogi 
 apisuchha9shh | ctx-Slucha 
 cq98hd98ladse | ctx-Epuent 
 q09jucidnionc | ctx-Igeegs
```

What I'm looking for is the 5th table that gets all names from other tables (that contains the id's) and give the names:

```
table5

customerId | adsId | campaignId |   contextId   |    Date    | amoutDue |   adsName  |campaignName| contextName
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234341233 | 4r4w3 |  cp123sifs | cbgvss23r23dd | 03-09-2021 |    50    | ad-google1 | cp-adWords | ctx-Okkels
4556666666 | 35533 |  cp453f44f | cb2d3d23dd33d | 04-06-2021 |    25    | ad-fbtests | cp-looki12 | ctx-Yumeis
3444468766 | 12345 |  cpef4f44r | ccascasca333s | 23-04-2021 |    13    | ad-bingpro | cp-cvccp53 | ctx-Niehok
6346522452 | qw324 |  cpfe4r333 | c23ddsasssd2f | 12-07-2021 |    71    | ad-maillan | cp-Pliiltr | ctx-Sluiru
3463466346 | 23423 |  cp1vt5rfr | kjhcbwiytcubp | 25-02-2021 |    41    | ad-cp-e312 | cp-Yellinf | ctx-Strogi
4534634346 | 534f3 |  cp4343ff4 | apisuchha9shh | 14-05-2021 |    36    | ad-gads2-4 | cp-Iuliucs | ctx-Slucha
7743646346 | wer32 |  cp4ffwefe | cq98hd98ladse | 12-03-2021 |    53    | ad-adProsk | cp-Ieventx | ctx-Epuent
2424233335 | r4w4r |  cpwerewff | q09jucidnionc | 05-06-2021 |    65    | ad-cpcB151 | cp-Shoofab | ctx-Igeegs
```

I tried to use `join` but I couldn't select all tables... My SQL in words would be:

`get campaingName from table 2 and create a row with the name where campaingId from table1 = to campaingId from table 2` the same for all fields...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `join` like this

```
select *
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     using (adsid) join
     table3 t3
     using (campaignid) join
     table4 t4
     using (contextid);
```

The above works because the `join` keys have the same names in the reference table and the original table (a best practice).  You can also use the more verbose:

```
select t1.*, t2.adsName, t3.campaignName, t4.contextName
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.adsid = t1.adsid join
     table3 t3
     on t3.campaignid = t1.campaignid join
     table4 t4
     on t4.contextid = t1.contextid;
```

If some of the ids are missing, then use `left join` instead of `join`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple with clause within big query to achieve this.

```
WITH TEST1 AS
(select a1.*,a2.adsName
from `<project_name.<dataset_name>.table1` a1, `<project_name.<dataset_name>.table2` a2
where a1.adsId=a2.adsId),
TEST2 as
(
select TEST1.*,a3.campaignName
from TEST1, `<project_name.<dataset_name>.table3` a3
WHERE TEST1.campaignId=a3.campaignId)

select TEST2.*, a4.contextName
from TEST2,`<project_name.<dataset_name>.table4` a4
WHERE TEST2.contextId=a4.contextId
```